# Sorting 2 columns in Linux

Tags: linux, sorting

My input file is as follows.

A 0
A 2
C 2
B 11
C 5
D 7
B 3

I want my output to be like below. Please help me with SORT command in linux.

Thanks.

B 11
B 3
D 7
C 5
C 2
A 2
A 0

The second column is first sorted and then the first column is arranged.

Comment: `sort` is terrible for arbitrary orders.

Comment: You should probably write your own sorting. The standard `sort` isn't much help for custom criterions. This should be easy in `python`, `js` or any scripting language you're comfortable with

Answer (score 2):

It can be done but it's not pretty:

```
for key in $(sort -n -k2 -r <inFile | awk 'ex[$1]==0{print $1;ex[$1]=1}'); do
    awk -vK=$key '$1==K{print}' <inFile | sort -r -n -k2
done
```

The command that's used within the `for` loop will return a list of keys (the letters) in order of reducing value, and with duplicates removed. The `sort` part ensures all lines are in reducing-value order (numeric, keyfield 2, reverse order), while the `awk` only prints the first of each key by using the "doesExist" associative array `ex[]` to discard subsequent ones. That gives you the keys `B,D,C,A` in that order.

Then, for each of those keys in that order, it will extract *all* the data from the input file *for that key,* and sort those based on the decreasing value.

The end result is the sorting of the key-sets by reducing *highest* value and the lines within each key-set by reducing value:

```
B 11
B 3
D 7
C 5
C 2
A 2
A 0
```